# How to add UIButton with UIPickerView cell?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a custom `UIPickView` ，in `(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view` custom `UIButton` clicked，but not working，what should I do? Please help us. Thanks

**My code:**

```
  - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
        UIButton *button;
        if (!button) {
            button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.bounds.size.width, 44.0);
            [button setTitle:_pickDataArray[row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            button.tag = 1000 + row;
        }
        return button;
    }

    - (void)pickButtonAction:(UIButton *)button{
        NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld",(long)button.tag);
    }
```

NO need this code

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{ }
```

updata code:

```
UIButton *button;
if (view == nil) {
    view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    if (!button) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.bounds.size.width, 44.0);
        [button setTitle:_pickDataArray[row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        button.tag = 1000 + row;
        [view addSubview:button];
    }
}
return view;


- (void)pickButtonAction:(UIButton *)button{
    NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld",(long)button.tag);//always not executed
}
```

Comment: self.view.addsubview(button) put this line in if condition after button.tag line check output

Comment: Added it，but button clicked not working

Comment: -(IBAction)pickButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld",(long)sender.tag);
    } use like this method

Comment: OK，but we don't use SB or XIB

Comment: but when i say that you use xib file its normal coding brother .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK，I see, Button click event block with UIPickTableViewWrapperCell

[image]

My code:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    id view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [view hitTest:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
     if (view == nil) {
        view = [[UIView alloc] init]; 
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        if (!button) {
              button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
              button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.bounds.size.width, 44.0);
              [button setTitle:_pickDataArray[row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
              button.tag = 1000 + row;
             [view addSubview:button];
        }
     }

    return view;
}
```

You just forgot to return UIView and add button to your view .

Comment: this view is null =.=

Comment: `pickButtonAction:` Always not executed

Comment: UIControlEventTouchDown use this @GhostClock instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Comment: in my case all time its call i change in one statement in your question @GhostClock check it try it